# Generalized expected Hamming distance

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, bit-strings

Let $x,y\in\{0,1\}^n$ be uniformly drawn at random from the set of all length-$n$ bitstrings $\{0,1\}^n$. Let $d(x,y)$ be the Hamming distance of two such bitstrings, i.e.  the number of positions at which the bitstrings differ.

Further, let $f:\{0,1\}^n \to \{-1,1\}$ and let $r=\frac{|f^{-1}(-1)|}{2^n}$ be the ratio of bitstrings where $f$ is negative to all bitstrings. I am wondering how to compute
$$\underset{x,y}{\mathbb{E}}[f(x)f(y)\;d(x,y)]$$
For symmetry reasons, I would think that this expression should only depend on the ratio $r$. **Is this intuition correct?** **EDIT: No, it's not as pointed out by the comments.**

For the constant function $f=+1$ with $|f^{-1}(-1)|=0$, it is easy to calculate the expression. It's just the expected Hamming distance
$$\underset{x,y}{\mathbb{E}}[d(x,y)]=n/2.$$ The calculation uses the fact that we know that to every $x$, there are precisely $\binom{n}{k}$ many $y$ at Hamming distance $d(x,y)=k$. So that
$$\underset{x,y}{\mathbb{E}}[d(x,y)]=\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\sum_{x,y\in\{0,1\}^n}d(x,y)=\frac{2^n}{2^{2n}}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} k= n/2.$$

However, I am now trying to generalize this calculation to other $f$. I would also be happy, for starters, with ideas on how to bound the expression.

Comment: At the moment, I don't really see why your intuition would be correct. Consider for example $n=2$, $f(0,0)=f(1,0)=1=-f(0,1)=-f(1,1)$ and $g(0,0)=g(1,1)=1=-g(0,1)=-g(1,0)$. Do you get the same expectation in both cases?

Comment: I see. My intuition is clearly wrong. That makes it even harder, I guess.